# How can I update the $scope in AngularJS when a server sided update occurs?

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, websocket, ngresource, ratchet

**Background**

1. I am trying to make a single page real-time application that uses a PHP , MYSQL back end and AngularJS frontend
2. My back end is using CakePHP framework which serves a JSON API and the front uses ngResource in AngularJS to access this API.
3. I have got 'Ratchet WebSockets for PHP' working, which can trigger a response to the browser via  websockets when something updates in the back end.

---

**My Incomplete Solutions**

**Solution 1:** Use the response via the websocket to update the AngularJS $scope object through some kind of $scope.model.push(websocket.data) method?

**Solution 2:** Use the response via the websocket to trigger Refresh on the ngResource which would refresh the $scope object completely?

---

**Question**

Are my solutions viable? and how could I achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to read events from the WS and populate them using `$emit` and `$broadcast`, then your controllers can subscribe to whichever events are relevant to them.

Take a look at:

[angular websocket factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334105/angular-websocket-factory/25348652)

[AngularJS and WebSockets beyond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299403/angularjs-and-websockets-beyond/26300758)